# Download thousands of images from URL PHP/AJAX

Tags: php, ajax

I have an array of image URLs and want to download images in my server through curl or file_get_content, but when I am downloading files I am getting corrupt jpg, png and webp files in my server, and I want to download multiple files one by one through ajax, like when I run an ajax request it should grab 10 or 20 images from the array and download them and run another ajax request right after one success and grab another 20 images from the array,

```
$images = array('http://ensemblepakistan.com/wp-content/uploads/2018/06/11.jpg',
'https://ensemblepakistan.com/wp-content/uploads/2018/08/SHK-242-3.jpg',
'https://ensemblepakistan.com/wp-content/uploads/2018/08/SHK-242-1.jpg',
'https://ensemblepakistan.com/wp-content/uploads/2018/08/SHK-242-2.jpg',
'https://ensemblepakistan.com/wp-content/uploads/2018/08/SHBK-258-3.jpg',
'https://ensemblepakistan.com/wp-content/uploads/2018/08/SHBK-258-2.jpg',
'https://ensemblepakistan.com/wp-content/uploads/2018/08/SHBK-258-1.jpg',
'https://ensemblepakistan.com/wp-content/uploads/2018/10/SHBK-313-3-min.jpg'
);

foreach($images as $image) {
   $name = basename($image);
   $newfile = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] .'/test/'.$name;
   
    $ch = curl_init($image);
    $fp = fopen($newfile, 'wb');
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FILE, $fp);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
    curl_exec($ch);
    curl_close($ch);
    fclose($fp);
}
```

Here's the code that i'm using right now

Answer (score 0):

Aside from Malwarebytes blocking this WP pages - the SSL cert seems to have an issue so remove https:// and make all calls to http://; I was able to easily grab your images via code like this:

```
<?php
$images = array('http://ensemblepakistan.com/wp-content/uploads/2018/06/11.jpg',
'http://ensemblepakistan.com/wp-content/uploads/2018/08/SHK-242-3.jpg',
'http://ensemblepakistan.com/wp-content/uploads/2018/08/SHK-242-1.jpg'
);

$imgcount = 0;
foreach($images as $image) {
   $img = file_get_contents($image);
    file_put_contents("image-".$imgcount.".jpg",$img);
    $imgcount = $imgcount + 1;
}
?>
```

Your images likely were corrupt because the SSL handshake (site has a bad cert) or the MIME type which you were saving as; your method should've worked also had you went through non-SSL URLs; the above example should suffice though.

Comment: Hi, thanks, but i want to grab images through ajax requests, like if you export products in woocommerce, it sends multiple short request to generate csv of products, i have 20,000 images to download, server is giving timeout error while downloading them all